# Differentiability on level sets of a locally Lipschitz function

Tags: derivatives, lebesgue-measure, lipschitz-functions

---

**Proposition**

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be locally Lipschitz continuous, and

$$Z := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid f(x) = 0 \}.$$

Then$Df(x) = 0$ for Leb$^n$-a.e. $\,x \in Z.$

Where, $Df(x)$ is derivative of $f$ at $x$.

(ByLawrence C. Evans, Ronald F. Garzepy, "Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions", Chapter 3, Theorem 3.3(i))

---

At the beginning of the proof, it is stated that

> Choose $x \in Z$ so that $Df(x)$ exists, and
> $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0} \frac{\textrm{Leb}^n(Z \cap B(x;r))}{\textrm{Leb}^n(B(x;r))} = 1;$$
> Leb$^n$ a.e. point$x \in Z$ will do.

for Leb$^n$-a.e. $\,x \in Z.$

Why is this true? If $\textrm{Leb}^n(Z \setminus\textrm{Int}(Z)) =0$, then this will be true in my opinion. But this is not always right. Could you give me some advice?

Comment: you can see theorem 1.35 page 55 chapter 1 from the same reference.

Comment: @Hamza You are my hero!!!! Thanks!!